# How to cancel a thread in swift

Tags: ios, swift, automatic-ref-counting, swift5

I am facing a problem where a class instance is not being deallocated, so the app gets stuck. The class which is causing the problem is

```
import Foundation

class ResponseTimeoutQueue{

    private let mMsgOut: [UInt8]

    private let mResponseMsgId: Int

    private let mTimeoutMilliSec: UInt32

    private let mNumRetries: Int

    private var timeoutWorkItem: DispatchWorkItem?

    init(responseMsgId: Int, msgOut: [UInt8], timeoutMilliSec: UInt32, numRetries: Int) {
        mResponseMsgId = responseMsgId
        mMsgOut = msgOut
        mTimeoutMilliSec = timeoutMilliSec
        mNumRetries = numRetries
    }

    func run() {
    
        // create a work item with the custom code
        timeoutWorkItem = DispatchWorkItem {
                 // Insert your code here
           
               var retryNum: Int = 0
               var doRetry: Bool = true
               while (doRetry) {
                   Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: TimeInterval(self.mTimeoutMilliSec))
                   // If we are here then it means the last send did not receive a response before
                   // timing out.  Write with no timeout or num retries so we don't spawn another
                   // ResponseTimeoutQueue.
     

                   retryNum += 1
                   if (retryNum <= self.mNumRetries) {
                       SessionController.sharedController.invokeWriteData(responseMsgId: self.mResponseMsgId, bytes: self.mMsgOut)
                   } else {
                       doRetry = false
                   }
               }
               // Notify the handler.
               NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .timeOutMessage, object: -1)
           }

          //Create dispatch group
           let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

          // execute the workItem with dispatchGroup
           DispatchQueue.global().async(group: dispatchGroup, execute: timeoutWorkItem!)

          //Handle code after the completion of global queue
           dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.global()) {
               }

            timeoutWorkItem?.cancel()
    }

    func interrupt() {
        timeoutWorkItem?.cancel()
        timeoutWorkItem = nil
    }
}
```

The calling of run() function occurs from

```
func writeNotify(responseMsgId: Int, buffer: [UInt8], timeoutMilliSec: UInt32, numRetries: Int) {
    if (timeoutMilliSec > 0) {
        mResponseMonitorThreadMap[responseMsgId]?.interrupt()
        let timeoutThread: ResponseTimeoutQueue =
        ResponseTimeoutQueue(responseMsgId: responseMsgId, msgOut: buffer,
                             timeoutMilliSec: timeoutMilliSec, numRetries: numRetries)
        
        timeoutThread.run()
        mResponseMonitorThreadMap[responseMsgId] = timeoutThread
    }
}
```

It is basically we are requesting data from radar and when we get the data we call

```
func cancelResponseTimeout(responseMsgId: Int) {
    mResponseMonitorThreadMap[responseMsgId]?.interrupt()
    if mResponseMonitorThreadMap.keys.contains(responseMsgId){
        mResponseMonitorThreadMap[responseMsgId] = nil
    }
}
```

But after some minutes of communicating with the radar the thread count of responseTimeoutQueue number is 65 or more. I commented the writeToNotify() function, then the application has no problem. I will attach the memory hierarchy screenshot. I have tried giving `timeoutThread = nil` after we call timeoutThread.run() but the class instance number is not changing. How to resolve the issue? Thanks in advance. [image: This is the thread count]

Comment: try this: `timeoutWorkItem = DispatchWorkItem { [weak self] in ... }`

Comment: You have as strong reference to self inside of your closure. That is why your class is not being deallocated. `self.mNumRetries` and `self.mResponseMsgId` and `self.mMsgOut`

Comment: Just a doubt can I use lazy var in let timeoutThread: ResponseTimeoutQueue =
        ResponseTimeoutQueue(responseMsgId: responseMsgId, msgOut: buffer,
                             timeoutMilliSec: timeoutMilliSec, numRetries: numRetries). 
ie insted of let timeoutThread can I use lazy var timeoutThread?

Comment: Do you mean make `timeoutThread` a lazy property of the class? I don't see why not. Maybe you can post another question on SO explaining what you are trying to do. Hard to tell what you want in a comment

Comment: @RobC yes I just meant that. Making timeoutThread a lazy property. Now the app is working fine after I made changes according to you, so I just asked as a doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a number of issues here. The first and probably most important is at this line:

```
Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: TimeInterval(self.mTimeoutMilliSec))
```

A `TimeInterval` is an alias for `Double` and it represents a number of **seconds**. If you want to sleep for say 500 milliseconds, you need `TimeInterval(500)/1000` or `TimeInterval(0.5)`.

I'm also not sure what the point of all the calls to `cancel()` is. The one in `run()` is a race condition since it might get invoked before the work item begins executing. The other one does nothing because `cancel()` will only cancel items that have not yet started executing.

You do have a strong reference cycle, but I think it would be broken if you set `timeoutWorkItem` to `nil` in the dispatch group completion handler.

Talking of the dispatch group: you only have one item, so you don't really need it. You can put a completion handler directly on the work item and set the property to `nil` there.

**Edit**

OK, just had another look. The biggest problem isn't the mega long timeouts, it's the fact that `cancel()` does not do what you think. This is the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchworkitem/1780910-cancel):

> Cancellation causes future attempts to execute the work item to return immediately. *Cancellation does not affect the execution of a work item that has already begun*.

[my italics]

I think you'd be much better off setting an `NSTimer` or a `DispatchSourceTimer` for the time out and cancelling it if you get a response and then it's event block can do the retry.